# How to check form field value before posting form - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form that currently works great with the exception that a user can input any value they want into one of the form fields. I would like to first check the field value when the user presses the submit button, before the form is actually submitted.

Where is the best place to do this, I am assuming in the views.py?

My objective is to check the `customerTag` value that the user inputs, and ensure the value they enter exists in the `CustomerTag` model field.

for my `views.py` I currently have:

```
def usersignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            email_subject = 'Activate Your Account'
            message = render_to_string('activate_account.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': '127.0.0.1:8000',
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            send_mail(email_subject,
                    message,
                    'example@example.com',
                    [to_email,],
                    fail_silently=False)
            return render(request, 'confirm.html',)
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

`forms.py` I have:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):# for ensuring fields are not left empty
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['customerTag'].required = True

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'customerTag',)
        labels = {
            'customerTag': ('Customer ID'),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'customerTag': ('Please contact Support if you do not have your customer ID'),
            }
```

The code above works, but allows the user to input anything they like into `customerTag`. I'm thinking I need to do something like:

```
def usersignup(request):
    customerTags = CustomUser.objects.values_list('customerTag', flat=True)
    userInput = #user inputted value into form
    match = False
    for tag in CustomerTags:
        if userInput == tag:
            match = True
    if match == True:
        #submit form
```

Is this the right direction? If so, what is the best way of obtaining the value entered into form by the user?

Some of the other posts I found were using javascript to check the form, I would rather use python if possible.

Comment: Read up on form field validation and in this case you might also want to read up on ModelChoiceField in the django docs. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access customerTag value in your view with:

```
customerTag = request.POST.get('customerTag')
```

and then check if it exists in your database

```
# we retrieved customerTag in the code above sample so we pass it to filter params
match = CustomUser.objects.filter(customerTag=customerTag).exists()

# and then continue with the stuff u wanted
if match:
     #submit form
```

but if you make an ajax call on form input before user hits submit on form it brings better ux to your website